# manipulating string information and regex. php

Tags: php, regex

i am trying to check for specific values in a table (checkout of shopping cart) and then display pickup dates based on those values. so if i am ordering a product that has a code for xmas only a xmas calendar will display. or if i order something for xmas and thanks the customer will get a calendar for both xmas and thanksgiving.

here is the code (i am quite sure i am not going about this the right way.) i am trying to tie into an existing shopping cart template system.. so i cant do direct queries.

```
<?php
foreach($this->rows as $i => $row){

if(preg_match("/thanks/",$row->dates)) { $thanks ='thanks';}else {$thanks = '';}
if(preg_match("/xmas/",$row->dates)) { $xmas ='xmas';}else {$xmas = '';}
if(preg_match("/newyears/",$row->dates)) { $newyears ='newyears';}else {$newyears = '';}

$mydates=$thanks.$xmas.$newyears;


//print_r($mydates);

}

?>

<?php
if(preg_match("/xmas/",$mydates)) { ?>
<tr><td class="key">mylabel</td><td>myselect box</td></tr>
<?php }?><?php
<?php
if(preg_match("/thanks/",$mydates)) { ?>
<tr><td class="key">mylabel</td><td>myselect box</td></tr>
<?php }?>
<?php
if(preg_match("/newyears/",$mydates)) { ?>
<tr><td class="key">mylabel</td><td>myselect box</td></tr>
<?php }?>
```

the print_r returns the correct values but then the above only displays one (the first) select of the item in the cart.

say someone orders from xmas and thanks. then the print_r returns xmasthanks
if they order thanksgiving print_r returns thanks

the html looks like normal select boxes in a column. they should be showing like the print_ but instead only show the last item type in the cart so if you order a xmas thing first and a thanks second then only the select from thanksgiving shows.

Comment: Could you post the result of the `print_r` and the html output of that script (the relevant parts at least)?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Something like this should work - I'm sure someone else has an easier and better way though.  Try to avoid preg functions for simple matches.  strstr or even strpos seemed like it would work fine here.

If you don't need it to create the whole table, just take out the table start and end lines. - And actually, now that I think of it, you could easily combine the two loops into one.

```
    <?php

    $datecodes = array();
    foreach($this->rows as $i => $row){

    if(strstr($row->dates, 'thanks')) { $datecodes[] = 'thanks';}
    if(strstr($row->dates, 'xmas')) { $datecodes[] = 'xmas';}
    if(strstr($row->dates, 'newyears')) { $datecodes[] = 'newyears'; }

    }




    if((is_array($datecodes)) && (count($datecodes) > 0)){

    $out .= '<table>';

    foreach($datecodes as $code){

      $out .= '<tr>';

        switch($code){

            case 'thanks':
                $out .= '<td class="key">Thanksgiving</td><td>';
                //Display Thanksgiving Calendar
                $out .= '</td>';
            break;

            case 'xmas':
                $out .= '<td class="key">Xmas</td><td>';
                //Display Xmas Calendar
                $out .= '</td>';
            break;

            case 'newyears':
                $out .= '<td class="key">New Years</td><td>';
                //Display New Years Calendar
                $out .= '</td>';
            break;
        }

      $out .= '</tr>';

    }

    $out .= '</table>';

    echo $out;
    }
    else{
    echo 'No Holiday Orders Found';

    }
?>
```